# Transposing columns to row in hive and spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have data frame which looks like below

```
Electricity_Network,   EnergyType, ContractType,   FY, n,  Annualised electricity bill - mean
Ausgrid ELECTRICITY,    MARKET, FY2021-1,   301743, 1592.09563
Ausgrid ELECTRICITY,    MARKET, FY2020-1,   291668, 1567.474588
```

I need to transform above to below using HiveQL commands

```
Electricity_Network,   EnergyType, ContractType,   FY, values  
Ausgrid ELECTRICITY,    MARKET, FY2021-1,   n-301743,   
Ausgrid ELECTRICITY,    MARKET, FY2021-1,,  Annualised electricity bill - mean-1592.09562980687 
Ausgrid ELECTRICITY,    MARKET, FY2020-1,   n-291668,   
Ausgrid ELECTRICITY,    MARKET, FY2020-1,   Annualised electricity bill - mean-1567.47458801269
```

Can anyone guide me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Lateral View`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView) with `explode` to achieve this transformation.

## Minimal Working Example:

### Setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS so_table
(
    Electricity_Network String,
    ContractType        String,
    FY                  String,
    n                   INT,
    Bill_Mean           FLOAT
)
    COMMENT 'SO Tmp'
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STORED AS TEXTFILE;

INSERT INTO so_table
VALUES ("Ausgrid ELECTRICITY", "MARKET", "FY2021-1", 301743, 1592.09563);
INSERT INTO so_table
VALUES ("Ausgrid ELECTRICITY", "MARKET", "FY2020-1", 291668, 1567.474588);
```

### Query:

```sql
SELECT t.Electricity_Network, t.ContractType, t.FY, `values`
FROM so_table t LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(array(concat("n-", t.n),
                                           concat("Annualised electricity bill - mean-", t.Bill_Mean))) exploded as `values`;
```